# Minimum password length for maximum entropy

Tags: security, hash, character-encoding, passwords

Assuming a SHA 256 hash and a completely random password using the extended ASCII charset, is there a specific length after which additional characters offer no increase in entropy, and if so what is this?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by “extended ASCII”?

Comment: Extended ASCII is a misnomer: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII

Comment: Extended ASCII includes characters between 80 and FF (as hexadecimal) inclusive. And yes, I plan to store passwords as hashes. Edit: Which, as mentioned above, is a misnomer. Sorry.

Comment: Solve *x* = 256 / *b*. For BASE64, *b* would be log2(64)=6.

Comment: Storing passwords as plain text or as an encryption is very insecure.

Comment: "Encrypted passwords are insecure?" Excuse me?

Comment: If someone has access to your database, and you store your passwords as encryptions, then if the hacker can discover the encryption method then it is trivial for her to decrypt every password in the table(s).

Comment: @larsmans: Since when has storing passwords as plain-text been advisable?  Or for that matter, in a reversible manner?

Comment: @larsmans: That's why standard practice is to hash a combination of the user's password combined with a salt value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SHA-256 has 256 bits, obviously.  The minimum UTF-8 character length is one byte, i.e. 8 bits.  Therefore, any password longer than 256/8=32 characters is <s>guaranteed</s> extremely likely to collide with a shorter one.

Is this what you meant?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. And I apologize for changing my original post to questioning SHA 256 and extended ASCII.

Comment: I don’t think SHA-256 is bijective for every input value less than or equal to 256 bits.

Comment: @Gumbo, if you are correct, then both this answer and Jerry's answer are totally misleading...

Comment: @Mark: The answers aren't really misleading.  From an information-theory POV, an N-bit string can store a maximum of N bits of information (so up to 256 in the case of SHA-256).  A *random* N-bit string stores *exactly* N bits of information, so truncating it (even with a transformation) must *necessarily* discard information (i.e. entropy).

Comment: @Oli: I believe your answer starts with the wrong assumptions. According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2, a birthday (collision) attack requires 2^(L/2) evaluations, where _L is the number of bits in the digest_. For SHA-256, L is a constant 256, _regardless of the length of the input_. On the other hand, password guessability depends on a lot more factors, and has nothing to do with the hash algorithm used.

Comment: @Mark: I'm not sure I understand the point you're trying to make.  The OP was talking about *random* passwords; so guessability doesn't come into it!

Comment: @Oli: My point is that the answer to the OP's question is **"No."** There is no 256-bit threshold. Your answer is based on a misconception of how hash algorithms work. A _brute force attack_ on a random password depends 100% on _password length_ (no 32 character limit). A collision attack depends on the length of the hash (32 characters), _which is the same regardless of password length_.

Comment: @Mark: I do understand how hash algorithms work, thanks!  The OP was asking about entropy in the context of random strings; my answer addresses that, and my earlier comment expands from an information-theory POV.  I haven't mentioned attacks anywhere.

Comment: @Oli: Sorry for the personal attack in my comment!

Comment: @Oli: Okay, after additional research I've drawn my conclusion. Probably not surprising to you, it is very similar to yours :-P. Please see the answer I posted, and see what you think.

Answer (score 4):

A hash doesn't increase entropy, it just, so to speak, distills it. Since SHA256 produces 256 bits of output, if you supply it with a password that's completely unpredictable (i.e., each bit of input represents one bit of entropy) then anything beyond 256 bits of input is more or less wasted.

Other than from a truly random source, however, it's really hard to get input that has one bit of entropy for every bit of input. For typical English text, Shannon's testing showed about one bit of entropy per *character*.

Comment: Passwords are an untypical genre of text, though.  

A good way to estimate the entropy of a password that concatenates a sequence of _independent_ words is the sum of the binary logarithms of each word's frequency rank (e.g., if "garden" is the 500th most frequent word in English, then it contributes about 9 bits).  

The entropy of a set phrase is much, much less than the entropy of the same number of independently chosen words.

Answer (score 3):

I have come to roughly the same conclusion as the others did, but with a different rationale.

Generally speaking, a preimage (brute force) attack on SHA-256 requires 2^256 evaluations, *regardless of password length*. In other words, a hash of a "password" that is thousands of characters long would still take an average of 2^256 tries to duplicate. 2^256 is about 1.2 x 10^77. However, a very short password, where the number of possibilities is less than 2^256, is even easier to break.

**The threshold is passed when the number of possibilities is greater than 2^256.**

If you are using ISO 8859-1, which has 191 characters, there are 191^n possible random passwords of length n, where n is the length of the password. 191^33 is about 1.9 x 10^75 and 191^34 is about 3.6 x 10^77, so the threshold would be at **33 characters**.

If you were using plain ASCII, with 128 characters, there would be 128^n possible random passwords of length n, where n is the length of the password. 128^36 is about 7.2 x 10^75 and 128^37 is about 9.3 x 10^77, so the threshold would be at **36 characters**.

Some of the other answers seem to imply that the threshold is always at 32 characters. However, if my logic is correct, **the threshold varies, depending on the number of characters you have in your character set**.

In fact, suppose that you used only characters a-z and 0-9, you would continue to add password strength up until your password was **49 characters** long! (36^49 is about 1.8 x 10^76)

Hopefully this answer gives you a mathematical basis for answering the question.

As a side note, if a birthday (collision) attack were possible on SHA-256, it would theoretically require only 2^128 evaluations (on average), which is about 3.4 x 10^38. In that case, the threshold for ISO 8859-1 would be at only **16 characters** (191^16 is about 3.1 x 10^36). Thankfully, such an attack has not yet been publicly demonstrated.

Please see the Wikipedia articles on [SHA-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2#Cryptanalysis_and_validation), [preimage attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_attack), and [birthday attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an "effective" limit. Password of any length will be effective if it is effectively created (the usual rules, no words, mixed numbers, letters, cases and characters). It is best to force user to follow these rules rather then limit length. But minimum length should be imposed, sth like 8-10 characters, to save the users from themselves.

Comment: This may be the case for human-chosen passwords.  But in terms of "random" passwords, I believe the OP is talking about entropy in the information-theory context.